# C++ variadic templates - NULL converts into int

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

I'm new to variadic templates in C++, so this question may seem kind of noobish to the experienced guys over here.

What im trying to do is create a `proxy function` that will be able to redirect my arguments to any other function using variadic templates.

My code is as follows:

```
template <typename Ret, typename ... Types>
Ret proxy_function(Types ... args)
{
    return MessageBoxA(args...);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::any retval = proxy_function<boost::any>(NULL, "123", "456", 0);
}
```

On compilation, the compiler outputs the following error:

```
1>Main.cpp(107): error C2664: 'int MessageBoxA(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'HWND'
```

However, when I supply the following code it works just fine:

```
template <typename Ret, typename ... Types>
Ret proxy_function(Types ... args)
{
    return MessageBoxA(NULL, args...);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::any retval = proxy_function<boost::any>("123", "456", 0);
}
```

Is there any reason in the world why the compiler won't be able to cast it to HWND type?

And another question I have in mind right now related to this issue - Is it possible to figure out the type of arguments inside a function?
I would like to be able to do this stuff:

```
template <typename Ret, typename ... Types>
Ret proxy_function(Types ... args)
{
    psuedo-code:
        for arg in args:
            do_stuff<type(arg)>(arg);
}
```

Thanks in advance, Aviv

Comment: Use `nullptr`. That's why it exists.

Comment: Well, for my first question - NULL is defined also as 0 and also as (void *)0, therefore these two types are not compatible with HWND.

a quick fix for this problem would be:

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::any retval = proxy_function<boost::any>((HWND)0, "123", "456", 0);
}
but I want to force my compiler to AUTOMATICALLY convert the 0 to HWND using reinterpret_cast.

Comment: If you have two questions, why not make two different questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integral literal of value 0 implicitly converts to pointer. But in the call it ends up as a run-time function parameter, which is not a compile time constant, and therefore does not convert to nullpointer (even if it's 0). Use C++11 `nullptr`.

---

By the way, look up "perfect forwarding".

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is defined as `0` and the literal `0` is implicitly convertible to a pointer.  This causes problems like the one you just mentioned so now there's a new type `nullptr_t` with object `nullptr` that is implicitly convertible to any pointer type and gives `null` (lowercase to represent the concept of `null` instead of thinking it gave `NULL`).

As for your second question in your particular usage you can use recursion like so:

```
    template <class T>
    void do_stuff(T && t){/* stuff here with t*/}

    template <class T, class ... Ts>
    void do_stuff(T && t, Ts && ... ts)
    {
        /* do stuff with t*/
        do_stuff(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
```